# Not woodworking, but..need a washable sealant that won't absorb grease to be applied over a painted wall

Tags: paint, varnish

I have painted a scene on the wall behind my kitchen stove. Now I need to protect the paint to that it 1) doesn't absorb cooking spatters and 2) is washable for the cooking spatters that do land on it and 3) won't change the paint colors.  I know this isn't exactly a woodworking question, but I'm looking for any help I can find.

Comment: Hi welcome to SE. By definition this isn't on topic for here so voting to close, sorry. There are a zillion other places to cold ask a question like this!

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/ looks like a good fit for this question